# Gcalcli is an invalid command after install

Tags: 14.04, command-line

Edit: As seen in comments gcalcli is installed in an other path than /usr/local/bin - so the `sudo ln -s` is not adviced. Check out [Gcalcli - no module named gdata.calendar.service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546397/gcalcli-no-module-named-gdata-calendar-service?lq=1)

I've installed gcalcli via `sudo apt-get install gcalcli` but somehow `gcalcli agenda` gives the following:

`Error: [gcalcli] is an invalid commandUSERNAME@COMPUTER:~$`

Yes, it is inline. When i write `gcalcli --help` I get the following peculiar output

```
Usage:

/usr/local/bin/gcalcli [options] command [command args or options]
```

alongwith the standard output.

I think i screwed up following this installation: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/command-line-cloud-gcalcli

Where it specifies:

`sudo ln -s ~/src/gcalcli/gcalcli /usr/local/bin/gcalcli`

This may have put it in the wrong path or something?

Answer (score 2):

Just found a solution that worked for me posted on github project page:

If you happen to have a `.gcalclirc` file in your home dir, **remove it** an run `gcalcli` again. It should redirect you to Google on your web browser to allow `gcalcli` to use your Google calendar data.